# Glasses underwater

Tags: optics, water, refraction, vision

So I figured the refraction of the cornea is based on the index of air and the vitrous humor to make a perfect image. Underwater this is messed with because water has the same index as the eye. Hence you can't see clearly underwater without making an air pocket with scuba goggles for example.

Would it be possible to compensate this by wearing regular glasses with a diopter that is equivalent to the difference in index between air and the eye, normally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible to make glasses that allow you to focus underwater. You could use a high-index material with a concave lens, or a low-index material (such as air) with a convex lens.

Comment: Do you have example (reference) where this has been done?

Answer (score 0):

Trivially no.  To see this, construct the glasses out of a material with the same refractive index as water.